# Any tricks to finding a lost jQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-validate, traversal

I'm working with jQuery.validate.  One of its options is "success" where a function can be called upon valid user entry on a form.  The only argument that can be passed is "label" which (as I understand) is a dynamically added label field to the right of the input element.

I need to perform a series of actions on a sibling "div" but I'm having enormous trouble trying to traverse to the div I want.  I can't even find where the label is.  Are there tricks to finding it?

I've used things such as `alert (label.parents('.formrow').html());` and `alert (label.parent().parent().parent().html());` and they all return "null"  ... `alert (label.html());` returns ""

Similar methods have worked for me in the past.  Once I find something I then employ `next()` or `find()` and all is well.  Is there another way?

PS. Example code:

```
success: function(label) {
  errorspotholder = label.parents('.formrow').find('.rederrorx');
  errorspotholder.removeClass('rederrorx').addClass('norederrorx').qtip('destroy');
            },
```

Comment: If I can remember correctly, the validation labels get appended to the start (or end) of the document and they are set with absolute positioning with an offset to the control that triggered the validation (or error).

You should use Firebug (http://getfirebug.com/) and inspect your HTML to find the element.

Comment: I just used Firebug and I can't find any location of "label" ... you think there's a way to pass another object to the jquery.validate success option?  for instance, element?  I try and it says "undefined" on alert.

Comment: hi Marko, your Firebug answer got be going in the right direction.  If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a bit case-specific and therefore probably not very useful to anyone else...

but what I did instead of using "label" was to declare a global variable based on another dynamic selector from jQuery.validate (in this case I used "element" from jQuery.validate's "errorPlacement").

It worked.

Marko also suggested in the comments finding lost elements by looking at the generated code from Firebug (getfirebug.com) console.  Great idea!  I didn't find my lost label but it should have worked and would probably work for someone else.